# How to revert to previous version after bad update

Tags: 14.04, wireless, updates, resolution, bios

I've had both ubuntu 14.04 and windows 7 running on my machine for a few months now and everything was running fine. I recently installed some updates in ubuntu, but had waited a while and so many updates were done simultaneously (so I'm uncertain which caused the problems I'm seeing). Now, when I start my comp and choose ubuntu, my screen is stretched and the wifi can't see any network in the area. I've already checked to make sure that my wifi toggle is on, and I haven't pressed any hotkeys. Everything works when I boot into windows, so it's not hardware.

I solved this problem by going into ubuntu's advanced options and choosing the previous version of ubuntu I had on the machine.

My question is: How do I get rid of the corrupted non-functioning version so that the computer will automatically boot into the working version when I choose Ubuntu in the GRUB menu?